# Sencha Popup Menu On Listview Item Tap

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

Using sencha touch 2.2 i am showing list of products in list view.

On each Item tap I want to open popup box to show each product detail like attached image below. I think its default in sencha by using showBy function. [For Reference](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.0.2/#!/api/Ext.Button-method-showBy).

But it could not align the arrow on each item tap accordingly.

I mean to say if I tap on Product List First Item Tap then arrow should be show with first item and if i tap on Product List last item then arrow should be show with it accordingly.

Also set the popup box in center

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sencha Fiddle for the code below: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1t1

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'listview',

    launch: function() {
        var popup = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
            html: 'popup',
            hideOnMaskTap: true,
            modal: true
        });

        Ext.Viewport.add({
            xtype: 'list',
            fullscreen: true,
            itemTpl: '{name}',
            data: [{
                name: 'item 1'
            }, {
                name: 'item 2'
            }, {
                name: 'item 3'
            }],
            listeners: {
                itemtap: function(list, itemIndex, target) {
                    popup.showBy(target, 'tc-bc');
                }
            }
        })
    }
});
```

What you might have overlooked is the `itemtap` event callback signature. The first parameter is the list, not the listitem.

The second argument of the `showBy` method describes the alignment. `tc-bc` means top center of the popup should align with the bottom center of the showBy target.

See http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-showBy